# Mathjax 2.6 - Font Size in Hidden Elements

Tags: mathjax

```
<style>
       .s1{font-size:12px}
</style>

<div class="s1">
        $\dfrac{1}{2}$
</div>
```

> The above code works fine and mathjax (version 2.6) renders it
>   correctly. The math is getting scaled down as expected.
>
> Suppose the above div is loaded with style "display:none" and the math
>   is displayed when clicking a link by changing display to block.
>
> In this case, the math is not scaled down.

I could see many have faced the same issue. This [github](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/Dealing-with-display:none) page explains this issue in detail. The problem happens because browser does not compute sizes of the sub-elements if style is "display:none". So mathjax processes it in seperate hidden elements.

> The solution suggested is to make use of "position: absolute; top: 0, left:0; width:0, height:0, overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;"
>
> Another approach is to reprocess math in such divs

But, is there any better approach to address this problem, possibly forcing the browser to calculate the size of display:none elements or by any other means?

Comment: I could solve this issue by using \tiny, \scriptsize, \footnotesize, \small,  \large, \Large, \LARGE (all caps), \huge, \Huge appropriately. is there any issue with this method?

Comment: No, there is no better way that I know of.  You can not force the browser to compute the size of elements contained in `display:none`.  The way to do that is to use the `visibility:hidden` that you already describe.